# 'Expected end_of_string but found colon' error when chaining where filters

Tags: filter, jekyll, liquid

I've just tried to bump my Jekyll version from `3.4.3` to `3.8.5` and when I run the build, I'm getting this error:

```sh
 Liquid Warning: Liquid syntax error (line 37): Expected end_of_string but found colon in "{{site.documents | where: "belongs_to_group", page.group | where: "lang": lang | sort: "page.date" | reverse }}"
```

What has changed in chaining `where` filters? I cannot seem to find anything in the docs.

When I only include one `where` filter, the variable gets properly assigned.

```rb
{% assign boxes = site.documents | where: "belongs_to_group", page.group %}
```

As soon as I add another one, I get the said error.

Here a full example on how I was able to assign the veraiable in a previous Jekyll version.

```rb
{% assign boxes = site.documents | where: "belongs_to_group", page.group | where: "lang": lang | where_exp: "item", "item.start_datetime > site.time" | sort: "start_datetime" %}
```

How can I still add those filters in the new Jekyll version?

Comment: Is there a public repository that I can clone and test..?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the issue here might be in this snippet:

```
where: "lang": lang
```

The key and value should be separated by a comma ([Jekyll docs](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/liquid/filters/)).

```
where: "lang", lang
```

Your other `where` clause is formatted correctly, which is why it isn't throwing an error when you include only that one.

Comment: Great catch Max! I saw it later as well and was annoyed by the the time I’ve wasted on this. :) I’m still puzzled though why it seemed to work with the former version...